# Adding menu items in horizontal display

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a vertical menu bar (like all website) ... I want to add a vertical sub-menu in one of the elements.

This is what I currently have:

[Current Contact Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hq0GK.png)

and this is what I want:

[Required Contact Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cP4ov.png)

Anyone have any idea how can I achieve this? NOTE: I tried using tables but it didn't show with the list background and came out with a transparent one!

**UPDATE:**

This is what I have including the table I trued to add ... (I'm sorry the code is a bit long).

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">PAGES</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="about.html">About Page</a></li>
            <li><a href="page-left-sidebar.html">Page with Left Sidebar</a></li>
            <li><a href="page-right-sidebar.html">Page with Right Sidebar</a></li>
            <li><a href="page-full-width.html">Full-width Page</a></li>
            <li><a href="faq.html">F.A.Q</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="typography.html">TYPOGRAPHY</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="typography.html#Heading">Heading Tags</a></li>
            <li><a href="typography.html#Column">Column Styles</a></li>
            <li><a href="typography.html#Highlight">Highlights</a></li>
            <li><a href="typography.html#List">List Styles</a></li>
            <li><a href="typography.html#Block">Blockquotes</a></li>
            <li><a href="typography.html#Image">Image Placement</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="porto-3cols.html">PORTOFOLIO</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="porto-2cols.html">Porto - 2 Columns</a></li>
            <li><a href="porto-3cols.html">Porto - 3 Columns</a></li>
            <li><a href="porto-4cols.html">Porto - 4 Columns</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="shortcodes.html">SHORTCODES</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="shortcodes.html#Toggle">Toggle</a></li>
            <li><a href="shortcodes.html#Tabbed">Content Tabs</a></li>
            <li><a href="shortcodes.html#Caption">Image Caption</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sample Submenu</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Sample 01</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sample 02</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sample 03</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="blog.html">BLOG</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.php">CONTACT</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="porto-2cols.html"><img src="pix/portopix/porto_3cols_09.jpg" alt="Sample Image" />ASD</a></li>
        <li>
            <table style="background:inherit">
                <tr>
                    <td>asd</td>
                    <td>asd</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you mean Horizontal menu bar?

Comment: Could you provide some sample code of what you have?

Comment: have you tried unordered list..??

Comment: added a code sample of what I have till now (for the menu bar)

Comment: @JamieDixon: Yes, a horizontal menu bar

Comment: @ramsesoriginal: provided, please check question.

Comment: @Madhav: Yes, please check code sample.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your last part (the bullet point with the table) with:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="porto-2cols.html"><img src="pix/portopix/porto_3cols_09.jpg" alt="Sample Image" />ASD</a>
        <div id="submenu">
            <h3>Title</h3>
            <ul>
                <li> first </li>
                <li> second </li>
                <li> third </li>
                <li> fourth</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

(By the way, you forgot a `</li>` in your code)

and add the following to your CSS stylesheet:

```
 #submenu {
     width: 130px;
 }

 #submenu ul {
     width: 100%;
 }

 #submenu li{
     width: 50px;
     display: inline-block;
 }
```

which would achieve a effect similar to what I suppose you want to achieve. Clearly you'll have to adjust the values according to your needs.

Here you have a example of how this could look:
http://jsfiddle.net/ramsesoriginal/4ML6G/

**Edit:**
What I thought you want to get (and are getting with my code) is :

```
 +------------------+
 |                  |
 +---+--------------+
     |              |
     +--------------+
     |              |
     +--------------+
     |              |
 +------------------+
 |                  |
 +---+--------------+
     |              |
     +--------------+
     |              |
 +------------------+
 |                  |
 +---+--------------+
     |              |
     +--------------+
     |              |
     | +---+  +---+ |
     | +---+  +---+ |
     | +---+  +---+ |
     | +---+  +---+ |
     +--------------+
```

If you look at the jsfiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/ramsesoriginal/4ML6G/ ) you'll see that it is like that. Are you trying to get something different?

Comment: didn't work with me ... it gave the table-like part out of the list!

Comment: and is coming out as a nested list

Comment: Yes, this is what I want, but when I appended it to my code, nothing happened ... it appeared as a linked list (sub menu tree)

Comment: Have you looked at the Jsfiddle? If yes, have you added the code correctly, including the id attribute (or a class, or whatever), and the CSS code? The CSS is important, as it styles to list to be such a box.. without it your default styling will apply

Comment: What browser are you using? Did it look right in the jsfiddle?